# python unpacking How to instantiate a list of object with one-liner

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-instances

I have similar objects i'd like to instanciate with one-liner from class Foobar

```
class Foobar():
    
    def __init__(self, path, scale, baz):
        self.path = path
        self.scale = scale
        self.baz = baz
```

i tried this:

```
listobj = [objA, objB, objC] = [Foobar("/picture_foobar.png", 0.5, baz=MAX_CST)]*3
```

or

```
objA, objB, objC = 3*Foobar("/picture_foobar.png", 0.5, baz=MAX_CST)
```

i got:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

also:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'Foobar'
```

Comment: Please see the [intro tour,](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) the [help center,](https://stackoverflow.com/help) this post on [how to ask a good question,](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to provide a [minimal reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Without providing any code for your Foobar class we can't really help.

Comment: edited , thats a general example

Comment: So it's not really clear what you're trying to do, but it looks like you're trying to create three instances of an object with the same parameters, and put them in a list? Do `[Foobar(...) for _ in range(3)]`

Comment: I answered the majority of your question, but a note: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` makes no sense from the code provided. I'm guessing you have other code using it that triggered that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `list` multiplication here, because that would make three *aliases* to the *same* object (that is, `objA is objB is objC`, and changing through one name, e.g. `objA.scale = 0.75`, would change all of them). The best you could do is:

```
objA, objB, objC = [Foobar("/picture_foobar.png", 0.5, baz=MAX_CST) for _ in range(3)]
```

which uses a simple listcomp to construct three different `Foobar`s (with the same arguments), then unpacks it to each of the three objects in question. If you need the `list` itself as well, you can do:

```
objA, objB, objC = listobj = [Foobar("/picture_foobar.png", 0.5, baz=MAX_CST) for _ in range(3)]
```

but be aware that the contents of `listobj` will be aliases to the named objects you unpacked to (e.g. `listobj[0] is objA`, `listobj[1] is objB`, etc.).